# Cargar PDF con iframe en Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy trabajando con un modal al que cargo pdf en sus tabs, el detalle que tengo es que en Internet Explorer no se carga dentro de la tabs, estoy utilizando iframe para realizar la carga, funciona bien en edge, firefox, opera, chrome, pero en IE (el cual necesitan en la empresa trabajarlo si o si), me genera una pestaña en la parte inferior con la opcion de guardar, abrir y cancelar.

```
Object.keys(sections).forEach(function (section) {
// Crear nombre de archivo
var file = "./files/".concat(id, "_").concat(sections[section], ".pdf"); // Verificar que existe archivo
fileCheck(file, // Función a ejecutar si existe el archivo
function () {
$('#' + section).html("<iframe src=\"".concat(file, "#scrollbar=0&embedded=true&zoom=120\" type=\"application/pdf\" class=\"margenfilemodal\" style=\" \" width=\"100%\" height=\"600px\" /> </iframe>"));
}, function () {
$('.' + section).hide();
});
});
```

Aqu[i lo que necesito es que se cargue dentro del recuadro del modal.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto por otra parte es lo que me entrega al ir a los tabs del modal, la opcion de abrir, guardar o cancelar...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces busco alguna configuracion extra que para IE permita ver el documento y no descargarlo o abrir.

Comment: Mis condolencias por tener que usar IE... ¿Has probado a, una vez descargado, abrir el PDF con el IE? Botón derecho sobre el archivo, Abrir con... -> Internet Explorer. Si no te sale en la lista de aplicaciones es porque en tu PC no está configurado como visor por defecto, pero deberías poder solucionarlo: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows_10/internet-explorer-11-not-opening-pdf-and-how-to/f678708f-4864-4072-8077-6bcfa68f1318